# How to use materialize css grids or react bootstrap grids to show 3 items in each row from a mapped out response in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, grid, array.prototype.map

I am trying to show a three or four response items from a mapped out response on the same row. I have looked at other stack overflows but their questions were slightly different and I didnt know how to implement the example to mine.

I have tried to use both bootstrap as well as css materialize grids to do the job. However the documentary doesnt show for mapping examples which I have. Also have tried to add className of "row" to parent div and the className of "col" to children divs just as docs have said. But it just repeats the same item over and over again. I want each individual item to display just once.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import LoadingIndicator from "./loadingIndicator"

const API_KEY="something";
const API_KEY2="something1";
const API_KEY3="something2"

class Recipes extends React.Component {

    state= {
        ingredients:[this.props.ingredients],
        loaded:false
    }

    handleChange=(e)=> {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit=(e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        axios.get(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY3}&q=${this.state.name}`)
            .then(res=> {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({
                    ingredients:res.data.recipes,

                })
            })
    }


    render() {  



        const recipeList = this.state.ingredients.length >0? this.state.ingredients.map((ingredient)=> {
            return(
                <div className="row" key={ingredient.recipe_id}>
                   <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                    <img className="recipeImage" src={ingredient.image_url}/>
                    <p>{ingredient.title}</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
            )
        }) : <LoadingIndicator loaded={this.state.loaded}/>
        return(
            <div style={{padding:50}}>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Food Name or Ingredient: </label>
                <input
                    id="name"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    className="formText"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="type in ingredient or recipe"
                 />
                 <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
            </form>
                <div style={{marginTop:100}}>
                    {recipeList}
                </div>   
            </div>
        );
    }

}


export default Recipes;
```

So so far I have gotten it to show, but with the same response item just repeated three times in the same row. I want each individual item to show just once on each row

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function has an optional argument for `index` which can be used to track the current `index` of the item in the iteration, as well as an argument for the array itself that is being iterated.

What you essentially want to do, is create the `div.row` opening tag on the start of every 0th, 3rd, 6th... and so forth iterations. You also want to close the tag on every 2nd, 5th, 8th iterations. So you move that code into an if condition using the `index` attribute.

```
this.state.ingredients.map((ingredient,i, ingredientList) => {
    if (ingredientList.length == 1) { //if only one item in the list add starting and closing tags
        return (
           <div className="row" key={ingredient.recipe_id}>
               <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <img className="recipeImage" src={ingredient.image_url}/>
                <p>{ingredient.title}</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       )        
    else if (i%3 === 0){ 
       return ( //add opening tag at every multiple of 3
        <div className="row" key={ingredient.recipe_id}>
               <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <img className="recipeImage" src={ingredient.image_url}/>
                <p>{ingredient.title}</p>
               </div>
       )
    else if(i%3 === 2 || i === ingredientList.length-1){//add closing tag if last item or 2nd, 5th, 8th...
       return (
             <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <img className="recipeImage" src={ingredient.image_url}/>
                <p>{ingredient.title}</p>
             </div>
         </div>
       )
    else { //Only add element otherwise
       return (
              <div className="col s12 m6 l3">
                <img className="recipeImage" src={ingredient.image_url}/>
                <p>{ingredient.title}</p>
             </div>
       )
    }
});
```